# Implementing the ∞-norm

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, programming

To write a program in Mathematica, I need to define $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ of an expression in a closed interval. Can you help me?

For example

$\qquad \|(\pi.Sin[x]+\pi . Cos[y]+\pi.Sin[x]. Cos[y.\pi])\|_{\infty}$ in $[-3,\, 3]\times[-3,\, 3]$.

I tried using `MaxValue` but could not make it work.

Comment: Have a look at `Norm`, specifically the form `Norm[v, Infinity]` where `v` is your argument

Comment: Show what you have tried.  Under the last question that you posted, and [that you just deleted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133600/12), we showed a concrete example of how to use `MaxValue`.